# Error when running LSTM model, Loss: NaN values

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm

My LSTM model using Keras and Tensorflow is giving `loss: nan` values.

I have tried to reduce the learning rate but still get nan and decreasing overall accuracy, and have also used `np.any(np.isnan(x_train))` to check for nan values that I may be introducing myself (no nan's were found). I also read about exploding gradients and cant seem to find anything to help with my specific issue.

I think I have an idea of where the issue may be but not quite sure. This is the process I implemented to build `x_train`
For example:

```
a = [[1,0,..0], [0,1,..0], [0,0,..1]]
a.shape() # (3, 20)

b = [[0,0,..1], [0,1,..0], [1,0,..0], [0,1,..0]]
b.shape() # (4, 20)
```

To ensure that the shapes are the same I append a vector `[0,0,..0]` (all zero's) to `a` so the shape is now `(4,20)`.

`a` and `b` is appended to give a 3D array shape `(2,4,20)`and this forms `x_train`. But I think appending the empty vectors of 0's is for some reason giving me a `loss: nan` whilst training my model. Is this where I could be going wrong?

n.b. `a+b` is a numpy array and my actual `x_train.shape` is `(1228, 1452, 20)`

•Edit• `model.summary()` added below:

```
x_train shape: (1228, 1452, 20)
y_train shape: (1228, 1452, 8)
x_val shape: (223, 1452, 20)
x_val shape: (223, 1452, 8)
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
unified_lstm (UnifiedLSTM)   (None, 1452, 128)         76288     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_v2 (Batc (None, 1452, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
unified_lstm_1 (UnifiedLSTM) (None, 1452, 128)         131584    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_v2_1 (Ba (None, 1452, 128)         512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1452, 32)          4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1452, 8)           264       
=================================================================
Total params: 213,288
Trainable params: 212,776
Non-trainable params: 512
```

Screenshot of nan is below:
[image]

Comment: This seems to be a problem of exploding gradients. You can try to add some Dropout layers in between the Dense layers. Also, try using an RMS prop optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use `Masking()` layers available in keras with `mask_value=0`. This is because when using empty vectors they are calculated into the loss, by using `Masking()`, as outlined by keras the padding vectors are skipped and not included.

As per keras documentation:

'*If all features for a given sample timestep are equal to mask_value, then the sample timestep will be masked (skipped) in all downstream layers (as long as they support masking)*'

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you check the following:-

1. The output of your Batch Normalisation Layer. Once, I encountered a similar problem, where loss was coming out to be "nan". When I checked the Normalization output, it's was all zeros. Maybe, that's what made loss to be "nan".
2. The Possible reason for NaNs could be too high of a learning rate. Try reducing it bit and check the output.
3. If you are using RMSProp, try Adam instead.
4. As your `dense_1` layer has shape of (None, 8), I am assuming you are working on some sort of classification problem. Because, we use log loss in here, sometimes, 
   precision errors also come into play. If you are using float16, change the precision to float32.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of padding all zeros vector, you should use a dummy feature. That is, your one-hot feature vector will increase size to `(21,)`, e.g., `[0, 0, 0, ..., 1]` of size 21 with the last dimension for dummy padding.

I also advise you to use index-based input instead of explicit one-hot vector, where each one-hot vector can be replaced by the index of its 1, e.g., `[0, 0, 1, ..., 0]` becomes 2. Keras support this index-based input style with its embedding layer. This will be easier to use and more computationally efficient.

Comment: I will try this. But does this also mean that my label vector will become (9,) instead of (8,) as they are also padded, and the dummy feature will need a class label?

Comment: Update: I've attempted this and used (21,) and (9,) and still get nan values.

Comment: That means there are more than one reason your code gets nan. I cannot see it based on the information in your question. You should add a small stand-alone code to reproduce the issue.